# UISlider to change UIImage brightness/contrast in Swift Playground is very laggy.

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am currently creating a filter app. The user has the option to change brightness, contrast, etc.

I have implemented the ability to change these attributes of the image and it currently works but when I test this in Xcode Playgrounds the slider is extremely slow and makes Xcode very laggy.

I assume this is because I have written this in a very inefficient way. I don't want to copy and paste all of my code to Stackoverflow (I want to avoid making this too complicated) so I have uploaded it on Github. [Located Here](https://github.com/Maxnelson997/FiltersPlayground) if you download the repo and open the playground up it is 100% running and if you test the slider you will see it is very laggy.

I think what is making it so laggy is that I am reseting the image view every time the slider value is changed resulting in a new UIImage being assigned to it every fraction of a second. Here is a tiny snippet of what I I just said, in code. You will probably still have to look at the code I posted on [github](https://github.com/Maxnelson997/FiltersPlayground) since I made some protocols and classes

```
slider.addTarget(c, action: #selector(c.BrightnessChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

func updateBrightness(sender:UISlider) {
    controls.brightness(sender.value)
    img.image = controls.outputUIImage()
}
```

I genuinely have no intention asking for a solution without having tried myself; I have searched all over the interwebs to figure this out with no success.

Thanks Stackoverflow homies!

Comment: Without looking at your linked code, a few questions. (1) Are you using `CIColorControls`? CoreImage is *the* way to go. (2) Are you using a `GLKView`? That's also the way to use the GPU instead of the CPU. (3) Is it also "laggy" on a real device? If you said "yes" to the first two questions, you probably *will* see some lagginess in the simulator.

Comment: Yes CIColorControls with CoreImage Imported. Not sure what a GLKView is but ill check it out. It isn't laggy on my device, dumb of me not to test it in the simulator yet, ill go do that.

Comment: A GLKView is a subclass of UIView that uses OpenGL (and the GPU) to draw. I have one (soon to be two) photo effect pos that use it. Unlike a UIImageView, it takes a CIImage as the input. You'll need to set up an EAGL context, but performance is tremendously better for "real time" updating of images. This blog (with Swift 2 example) should help you - https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/

Comment: Sweet @dfd thanks for linking me to that tutorial! It's exactly what I needed to learn! Thanks. It solved my problem.